# Which Doctor Who episodes "explain" real life mysteries?

Tags: doctor-who, inspiration

While reading [8 Historical Mysteries That Would Make Great 'Doctor Who' Episodes](https://www.inverse.com/article/14588-8-historical-mysteries-that-would-make-great-doctor-who-episodes), I came across the following:

> Doctor Who has co-opted a number of historical figures and events, putting the Time Lord in position to explain some of the world’s biggest mysteries. We’ve had Agatha Christie’s disappearance, Shakespeare’s missing play, and the Mary Celeste’s missing crew.

I was a little confused as I had no idea those were real life mysteries. It got me thinking, **which Doctor Who episodes "explain" real life mysteries?**

Comment: You mean aside from the three you've mentioned?

Comment: @Valorum you can include those too (if you want), since I have no idea what they're talking about.

Comment: @RedCaio Agatha Christie's disappearance: *The Unicorn and the Wasp* (S4E7, one of the better historical DW episodes). Shakespeare's missing play: *The Shakespeare Code* (S3E2, silly and forgettable). The *Mary Celeste*'s missing crew: I hadn't heard of this one, but apparently it's a First Doctor serial.

Comment: Aside from real historical mysteries like the ones mentioned, they've also given explanations for various claims of cryptozoological creatures and supernatural mysteries, like the Loch Ness Monster (Terror of the Zygons), the Yeti (The Abominable Snowmen), vampires (State of Decay), devils (The Daemons), etc.

Comment: @Hypnosifl And let's not forget the "three possible versions of Atlantis"!

Comment: There was also a hint that it what the Tardis what sank Titanic. But at the end it wasn't the real Titanic.

Comment: @Randal'Thor so... are you saying we should do a CW answer?

Comment: @RedCaio I wasn't, but that might be a good idea.

Comment: @Randal'Thor started one

Comment: What do you count as a "mystery"? I suppose the eruption of Vesuvius (which turns out to have alien involvement) doesn't count?

Comment: @Rand I think it's a stretch but it still might count. I'm pretty open - if you think something counts, then the more the merrier :)

Comment: what about Vincent? Van Gogh. I guess its not mystery, but comes under a reallife personality....

Comment: Might mention Shakespeare scene in The Chase, with the ideas for Hamlet?

Answer (score 18):

<sub>This is a Community Wiki answer - please add examples/details as needed.</sub>

**Real-life mysteries:**

- The [Mary Celeste's missing crew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Celeste) was addressed in the First Doctor story [*The Chase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chase_(Doctor_Who)) (Season 2, Serial 8).
- The ending of Dickens's unfinished novel [*The Mystery of Edwin Drood*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mystery_of_Edwin_Drood) was addressed in the Ninth Doctor story [*The Unquiet Dead*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unquiet_Dead) (Series 1, Episode 3).
- Shakespeare's [missing play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare%27s_plays#Lost_plays) and the [Dark Lady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare%27s_sonnets#The_Dark_Lady) of his sonnets were addressed in the Tenth Doctor story [*The Shakespeare Code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shakespeare_Code) (Series 3, Episode 2).
- Agatha Christie's [disappearance](http://www.the-line-up.com/agatha-christie-disappearance/) was addressed in the Tenth Doctor story [*The Unicorn and the Wasp*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unicorn_and_the_Wasp) (Series 4, Episode 7).
- Queen Nefertiti's [disappearance](http://nefertitikatiemay.weebly.com/the-disappearance-of-nefertiti.html) was addressed in the Eleventh Doctor story [*Dinosaurs on a Spaceship*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaurs_on_a_Spaceship) (Series 7, Episode 2).

**Alternative explanations of events not generally considered mysterious**

- The [burning of Rome](http://www.eyewitnesstohistory.com/rome.htm) is addressed in the First Doctor story [*The Romans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Romans_(Doctor_Who)) (Season 2, Serial 4).
- How life began on Earth is addressed in the Fourth Doctor story [*City of Death*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Death) (Season 17, Serial 2).
- The cause of [the Great Fire of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Fire_of_London) was addressed in the Fifth Doctor story [*The Visitation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Visitation_(Doctor_Who)) (Season 19, Serial 4).
- The [extinction of the dinosaurs](http://www.ucmp.berkeley.edu/diapsids/extinction.html) was addressed in the Fifth Doctor story [*Earthshock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthshock) (Season 19, Serial 6).
- The cause of [the Big Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) was covered in the Fifth Doctory story [*Terminus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminus_(Doctor_Who)) (Season 20, Serial 4).
- [Haemophilia in the descendants of Queen Victoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haemophilia_in_European_royalty) was addressed in the Tenth Doctor story [*Tooth and Claw*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooth_and_Claw_%28Doctor_Who%29) (Series 2, Episode 2).
- The [destruction of Pompeii](http://www.eyewitnesstohistory.com/pompeii.htm) was addressed in the Tenth Doctor story [*The Fires of Pompeii*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fires_of_Pompeii) (Series 4, Episode 2).
- The Easter Island statues were addressed in the  Eleventh Doctor story [*The Impossible Astronaut*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Impossible_Astronaut) (Series 6, Episode 1).
- Neil Armstrong's [famous flub upon setting foot on the Moon](http://www.snopes.com/quotes/onesmall.asp) was addressed in the  Eleventh Doctor story [*Day of the Moon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_Moon) (Series 6, Episode 2).

---

Bonus round: **Cryptozoological creatures and supernatural mysteries**:

- The [Yeti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeti) were addressed in the Second Doctor story [*The Abominable Snowmen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Abominable_Snowmen) (Season 5, Serial 2).
- [Demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_(disambiguation)) were addressed in the Third Doctor story [*The Daemons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_D%C3%A6mons) (Season 8, Serial 5).
- The [Loch Ness Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_Ness_Monster) was addressed in the Fourth Doctor story [*Terror of the Zygons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terror_of_the_Zygons) (Season 13, Serial 1) and alternately in the Sixth Doctor story [*Timelash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timelash) (Season 22, Serial 5).
- [Vampires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire) were addressed in the Fourth Doctor story [*State of Decay*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_Decay) (Season 18, Serial 4) and the Eleventh Doctor story [*The Vampires of Venice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vampires_of_Venice) (Series 5 Episode 6).
- The [Devil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil) was addressed in the Tenth Doctor story [*The Impossible Planet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Impossible_Planet) / [*The Satan Pit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Satan_Pit) (Series 2, Episodes 8-9).

Comment: [A useful Wikipedia resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_historical_characters) for this answer.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Haemophilia in the British Royal Family was a real thing :O

Comment: **Note** that the second section ("Alternative explanations") could potentially get very long, and doesn't strictly answer the question. I considered deleting it, but decided I should ask for opinions before doing so.

Comment: @tilley31 That's where the expression "blue blood" originates.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm not sure that Nefertiti is currently considered to have disappeared. The sources cited in [her Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nefertiti#Old_theories) suggest that despite earlier theories to the contrary, she remained influential through the end of Akhenaten's reign and into the early years of Tutankhamun's. Perhaps the item about her belongs in the "Alternative explanations" section.

Comment: @Blackwood Feel free to edit - it's a CW answer, after all :-)

Comment: Not sure if it has this place here, but The Doctor may have inspired Churchill his V sign in "Victory Of The Daleks". (Churchill never use it in the episodes, and the doctor uses him toward him in the end of the episod)

Answer (score 2):

I think the episode "Horror of Fang Rock" from 1977 is supposed to be an explanation for the Flannan Isles Lighthouse mystery of 1900. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horror_of_Fang_Rock#The_Ballad_of_Flannan_Isle)

Comment: As the first answer is marked "Community Wiki", feel free to edit this item into that answer.

Comment: Although now I have read the Wikipedia article you linked to, it seems that the episode was inspired by the Flannan Isles Lighthouse Mystery, but it doesn't attempt to explain it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch In that episode, the Rutans are responsible for the deaths on Fang Rock (off the south coast of England). However. the story is not the same as that of the Flannan Isles Lighthouse mystery, so I don't think it can be considered an explanation of the mystery.

Comment: @Blackwood Ah yes, I see your point. The deserted light house mystery was explained, but the island was fictionalized.